# How do I subscribe to all topics of a MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to connect a client which will monitor all the topics of the broker to respond to the events when I don't know what are names of topic.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Subscribing to `#` gives you a subscription to everything except for topics that start with a `$` (these are normally control topics anyway).

It is better to know what you are subscribing to first though, of course, and note that some broker configurations may disallow subscribing to `#` explicitly.

Comment: But the following link says that we should not be subscribing to # http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices. As it adds a lot of overhead on the broker. If the number of topics are too many.

Comment: @ralight is there any way to restrict this behavior in rabbitmq?

Comment: Don´t forget the leading "/", so it should be "-t /#"

Comment: @ChristianBaumann That is not correct. `#` gets you everything. There is no requirement to start with `/`, and I would actively encourage you not to do that - it adds an extra unnecessary level of hierarchy. If you split the topic string `/one/two//three` into its elements, you get `` , `one`, `two`, ``, `three`. So subscribing to `/#` won't receive messages published to `one`, for example.

Comment: @ralight I get your point, but when I execute `mosquitto_sub -d -u username -P password -t #` I get `Error: -t argument given but no topic specified.`

Comment: That is because the # is being swallowed by your shell as a comment. Try `mosquitto_sub -t '#'` or `mosquitto_sub -t \#`

Answer (score 87):

You can use `mosquitto_sub` (which is part of the `mosquitto-clients` package) and subscribe to the wildcard topic `#`:

```
mosquitto_sub -v -h broker_ip -p 1883 -t '#'
```

Comment: Thanks man! Nobody ever shows this simple but fundamental command!

Answer (score 20):

## Concrete example with existing MQTT server

mosquitto.org is very active (at the time of this posting).  This is a nice smoke test for a MQTT subscriber linux device:

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t "#" -v
```

The `"#"` is a wildcard for topics and returns all messages (topics): the server had a lot of traffic, so it returned a 'firehose' of messages.

If your MQTT device publishes a topic of `irisys/V4D-19230005/` to the test MQTT broker , then you could filter the messages:

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t "irisys/V4D-19230005/#" -v
```

To publish a test message said server:

```
mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org  -m "$NOW,QFNONS,B6,0677,JFKCDG" -t "irisys/V4D-19230005/"
```

Options:

- `-h` the hostname (default MQTT port = 1883)
- `-t` precedes the topic

## MQTT Anonymous Server Setup

After testing these concrete example or if said server is unavailable: an MQTT server can be quickly stood up on your own Ubuntu device:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
sudo apt install mosquitto mosquitto-clients
```

and configuring /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf to enable anonymous pub/ sub

```
# enable anonymous traffic through port 1833  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41852506/4953146
listener 1883 #https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
allow_anonymous true
```

without authentication for testing / proof of concept.  After validating on your LAN, you can forward 1883 WAN traffic for further testing.

Comment: Why have you just repeated an existing answer (by rem)?

Comment: @hardillb  Excellent  question! Rem has a fine answer, however, my example is 'concrete' in the sense that it points to a high traffic MQTT broker, so the reader can quickly / easily test from the command line.  mqtt.eclipse.org does not have regular traffic and was problematic.  I have tried to provide the community with a simple working 'concrete' example and avoid the pitfalls / obstacles I encountered.  I feel that my answer is the next evolution of rem's fine answer (I upvoted rem's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Use the wildcard "#" but beware that at some point you will have to somehow understand the data passing through the bus!