# How do I set authentication for a Mosquitto Broker?

Tags: authentication, mqtt, raspberry-pi3, mosquitto

I'm having an issue while configuring authentication on my Mosquitto.

As long as I allow anonymous connections on `mosquitto.conf`, I can access the broker (pub & sub) without any problems. But as soon as I enable authentication, I get a "`connection refused`". I have followed multiple tutorials on how to set up the authentication but I can't get it to work et can't figure out why.

I have installed Mosquitto 1.4.10 on a Raspberry PI 3 model B.

I have created a password file using the command : `sudo mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquitto/passwd test` and set the password to "test".

I have set `allow_anonymous` to false and password_file to `/etc/mosquitto/passwd` in `mosquitto.conf`.

Then, when I tried the command `sudo mosquitto_sub -t hello/world -u test -P test`, I get an "Error : Connection refused".

I have checked the password file, which seems to be correct (it has the right name and path `/etc/mosquitto/passwd` & contains an entry for my user "test").

**Question:**

Did I made a mistake in the configuration ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please share your mosquitto conf, the active lines are enough.

Comment: Also including the output from /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log to show any errors

Answer (score 10):

Taking the default mosquitto.conf add the following:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
allow_anonymous false

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Then use `mosquitto_passwd` to create the password file

```
mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquitto/passwd test
```

Then restart mosquitto with `service mosquitto restart`

(restarting the service after adding the password is important as the file is read at start up, or when mosquitto receives a HUP signal)

you should now be able to connect with the following `mosquitto_sub` command

```
mosquitto_sub -t hello/world -u test -P test
```

you can tail the /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log file to see if there are any errors

Comment: Careful with `-c` parameter, because it will completely wipe password file if it exists. For a non-password installation with a single user it may be fine, but if there're already other users in password file, or more than one user is to be added, is better to omit it.

Comment: you can add a new user to the file by just not adding any parameter to it:
mosquitto_passwd /etc/mosquitto/passwd iotdevice
This will add a new user to existing file